# Check if single column is equal to any multiple others

Tags: r

My question seems simple, but I just can't do it. I have a dataframe with multiple columns with the name starting with *coa* and another column *p* with values like A, D, F, and so on, which changes according to the id.

All I found is how to do this matching with a fixed value, let's say "A", as below:

```
df <-df %>%
  mutate(ly = any(str_detect(c_across(starts_with("coa")), "A")))
```

However, in my case, I want to compare to the column *p* specifically, where *p* changes, something like this:

```
df <-df %>%
  mutate(ly = any(str_detect(c_across(starts_with("coa")), p)))
```

In this case, I get the error:

```
x no applicable method for 'type' applied to an object of class "factor"
```

Any thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask on how to ask a question

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample data along with the expected output.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good place to use `dplyr::across`. You can run `vignette('colwise')` for a more comprehensive guide, but the key point here is that we can mutate all columns starting with "coa" simultaneously using the function `==` and we can pass a second argument, `p`, to `==` using the `...` option provided by across.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- tibble(p = 1:10, coa1 = 1:10, coa2 = 11:20)

df %>%
  mutate(across(.cols = starts_with('coa'), .fns = `==`, p))
```

Answer (score 0):

If we need to create a column, use `if_any`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df <- df %>%
      mutate(ly = if_any(starts_with("coa"), ~ str_detect(.x, p)))
```